# How can I pass an object between activities without starting the second activity

Tags: android

My app is about adding different objects to a cart.

I need the cart activity to recieve different objects without starting until I press the cart button.

For example, I have to add the object "x" from activity "A", then add another object "y" from activity "B" and then start activity "cart" and recieve objects "x" and "y" to do stuff with them.

Any help on how to do this is apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: implement your logic of adding / removing objects in a service and let it start your final Activity from there

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that.Simplest is using `static field`s. For example:

```
public class CartActivity extends Activity{
    public static Object X;
    public static Object Y;
    //...
}

public class A extends Activity{
    CartActivity.X = new X();
    //...
}


public class B extends Activity{
    CartActivity.Y = new Y();
    // Intent cartActivity = new Intent(...)
    startActivity(cartActivity);
}
```